# Android VideoView: How do I validate an illegal character in my url?

Tags: android

in my `android` app I provide a url but it contains an apostrophe **'**  in the url. This breaks the link and I get a `W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open <url here> java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider`when I check sure enough the link breaks next to the aforementioned character.

Here is the link:

```
https://foowebsite.com/videos/4/Manny's%20Awesome%20Videos/2019-05-09/92aede2e-ce54-49a4-9eca-86b3bb79fe73.mp4
```

Here is how I am consuming the url and modifying some of the known illegal characters.

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath(
        mCurrentItem.getmDownloadLink()
        .replace(" ", "%20")
        .replace("\\", "/")
        .replace("//", "/")
        .replace(":/", "://"));
//More video setup below...
```

My question is: how do I make the url take in that apostrophe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a single quote, you should use `%27` in URL instead of the single quote. And you can use this.

```
yourString.replaceAll("'","%27");
```

You can look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for URL encoding reference

Comment: thank you so much. Worked like a charm. this reference page will save me a lot of trouble in the future. The only trouble I seem to be running into is the fact that my video will sometimes play and sometimes I will get a "Error playing video" message. Don't really know what that's about. But I'll look into it.